# Enumeration items only for debug without using preprocessor directives

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, enums

Let's say I have an enum

```
enum MyEnum
{
    FirstItem,
    SecondItem,
    DebugOnlyItem
}
```

and I want `DebugOnlyItem` to be available for use only in debug, not in release. Is it possible to do without using `#if DEBUG` preprocessor directive? I was thinking of something like `Conditional` attribute except for fields but I couldn't find anything like that.

Comment: Why would you need it? Why can't you use preprocessor? any reason?

Comment: The only real reason is because `#if DEBUG` looks ugly, especially after they accumulate over months or years.

Comment: AFAIK there is no other way. If there's one I'd like to know. Btw microsoft itself uses preprocessor directives for this purpose, you can see many examples in [referencesource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/)

Comment: There might be a solution, you need to modify the IL afterwards to strip those things out. This is neither trivial nor recommended but can be a way.